# How to pass environment variables to Karate via Jenkins or maven command

Tags: karate

I have to pass username and password to Karate framework tests so that further operations can be done.
I am using the creds in karate-config.js file by using system.get.env etc command to fetch the value into a variable. It's working fine via IntelliJ run configuration but it's not working via Maven command or Jenkins pipeline
Maven cmd: mvn test -Dtest=abc -DdbuserId=efg -DdbUserPassword=hij

Comment: you will need to figure this out on your own, try seeing other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+maven+environment

Comment: You can try below command, use the property karate.env to pass the environment variable.                                                                                                                           
 mvn clean test -Dkarate.env="qa"